# How to use several different lists as argument?

Tags: r, loops, purrr

I'm trying to replace step by step all the for-loops I wrote (I read somewhere that it is bad programming :-( ) and I'm trying to achieve that with purrr.
So I basically understand the map()-functions as:

```
target <- map(list_which_is_argument_for_function,
              function)
```

But what do I have to do, if the argument lists aren't from e.g. the data frame I apply the map()-function to?

So let's say I have three data frames. 
df1 is essentially a collection of images: df1 = (Image_ID, File_Path, Date). df2 is a collection of site coordinates and dates: df2 = (X, Y, Date) 
... and df3 is a matching list, which contains references from every coordinate to their corresponding image. df3 looks like this: df3 = (Coordinate_Index, Image_Index). The lengths of the lists differ form each other.

Now I want to add columns to df3 for e.g. date diff calculation. In a for-loop I would do:

```
for(i in 1:length(df3$Coordinate_Index)) {
    df3$DateDiff[i] <- datediff_func(df1$Date[df3$Coordinate_Index[i]], df2$Date[df3$Image_Index[i]])
}
```

But if I do:

```
df3$DATE_DIFF <- map2(df1$Date[df3$Image_Index], 
                      df2$Date[df3$Coordinate_Index], 
                      abs(difftime(as.Date(), as.Date(), units = 'days')))
```

I get:

> argument “x” is missing, with no default

In other cases where I have to use extract() from the raster package, I need to give the coordinates with cbind() as an argument, resulting in a vector length error, because - obviously - if I have to bind X and Y together, it results in a list with double the length of the other argument list.

Could anyone explain the *purrr* way to me?

Comment: If is good to learn about these things (although I would start with base R and lapply). But you have been misled; for loops are fine. Except when you have very many iterations; let's say 1000 or more because then they might be too slow. They are really bad to use when a function is already vectorized; and this is often overlooked (e.g. `1:10  + 2`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` loops are not bad in themselves. Most of the `for` loops are inefficiently written which makes them perform bad as compared to other alternatives.

To change the `for` loop to `map` assuming output of `datediff_func` is a numeric value you can do :

```
df3$DateDiff <- purrr::map_dbl(seq_len(nrow(df3)), ~datediff_func(
               df1$Date[df3$Coordinate_Index[.x]], df2$Date[df3$Image_Index[.x]]))
```

Comment: Could you explain your solution? I'd guess seq_len(nrow) sets the length of the iteration like for(i in 1:length(...)), is that right? what does ~ do right before datediff_func?

Comment: Yes, `seq_len(nrow(df3))` does `1:nrow(df3)`. `~` is syntax (usually used in `tidyverse`) to indicate a function to be applied. It is similar to anonymous function.

Comment: I wrote a function date_diff to make it more easier to read. I wrote: `df3$DateDiff <- purrr::map2_dbl(seq_len(nrow(df3)), ~date_diff(df2$Date[df3$Image_Index[.x]], df1$Date[df3$Coordinate_Index[.x]]))`  Now I get: "argument “.f” is missing, with no default"

Comment: @Corbjn When you are using `~`, make sure you use `.x` and not `x`.

Comment: Of course I do. But it seems like there is an issue with the function. Full Error message is: Error in as_mapper(.f, ...): argument ".f" missing with no default

Comment: I am not sure how you have written `datediff_func`. I don't even know, what is present in `df1`, `df2` and `df3`. Error could be coming from any of these. First confirm if `datediff_func` works for one standalone input i.e `datediff_func(input1, input2)`. If it works then you can use it in `map`. If you have trouble debugging then you need to provide data for us to help.

Comment: Oh. The problem was a typo. I used map2_dbl and not map_dbl. Thanks for your endurance and help.